# SAPUI5 Structure , Component.js, manifest.json and Component-preload

Tags: sapui5

I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught Error: resource Main.view.xml could not be loaded from resources/Main.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors.

I am using Eclipse. I created my project so I restructured the folder like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPmT3.png)

then, i change my route on the view and controller respectly

Main.view.xml

```html
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="Deplo.Test.Controller.Main" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <Page title="Title">
  <content>
   <Text text="Prueba" />
   <Button text="Push" />
  </content>
 </Page>
</core:View>
```

Main.controller.js

```html
sap.ui.controller("Deplo.Test.Controller.Main", { });
```

and where can i download o load my component.js, manifest.json and Component-preload.js ???? be cause those folder are not created automaticly and why is the componentent preload used for ? if some one have some tutorial blog please let me know. I've been using sap web ide but here we don't have cloud connector so web ide is not for me :C

Comment: **Avoid blog posts** that are neither maintained nor complete. Instead, stick with the [documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic) which also includes ["Folder Structure: Where to Put Your Files"](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/003f755d46d34dd1bbce9ffe08c8d46a).

Answer (score 0):

You must define a custom `resourceroot`. You can do this by adding the `data-sap-ui-resourceroots` attribute:

```js
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "your.namespace.app": "./" }'>
</script>
```

Now the namespace `your.namespace.app` is configured to your root folder structure `./`.

After this, you need to prefix every controller and view with this namespace.

1. In your views change `controllerName`:

   from `controllerName="Controller.Main"`

   to `controllerName="your.namespace.app.controller.Main"`
2. In your controllers change the extend name:

   from `BaseController.extend("Controller.Main", {})`

   to `BaseController.extend("your.namespace.app.controller.Dashboard", {})`

> Btw a good starting point is the [UI5 Walkthrough](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db)!

Comment: i'm getting the same error :C 
Uncaught Error: resource Main.view.xml could not be loaded from resources/Main.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Watch my updated question

Comment: yes, i think i did i tried like this : data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"Deplo.Test": "./"}' and like this: data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"Deplo.Test": ""}' . Do you have any example so i cold compare ? an example without problem a hello world example but with the structure well done and the files

Comment: A good example is the UI5 Walkthrough from above. Takes 5 Minutes to follow the first 4 steps which should solve your problem.

Comment: Here is a finished example: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.05/code